# Getting "unexpected token" error for Rails request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following request spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'creating an instance', type: :request do
  it 'creates an instance' do
    headers = {
      'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'
    }

    post '/api/v1/instances', params: {
      instance: {
        instance_id_string: 'abc123',
        public_hostname: '0.0.0.0'
      }
    }, headers: headers

    expect(response.body).to eq('asdf')
  end
end
```

When I run it, I get:

> ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError:
>          767: unexpected token at 'instance[instance_id_string]=abc123&instance[public_hostname]=0.0.0.0'

I have no idea what could be wrong with the way my test is written. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Content-type is application/json. You should **cast** params hash to json.

```
params = { instance: {
    instance_id_string: 'abc123',
    public_hostname: '0.0.0.0'
}}
post '/api/v1/instances', params: params.to_json, headers: headers
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing my test to the following worked:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'creating an instance', type: :request do
  it 'creates an instance' do
    params = {
      instance: {
        instance_id_string: 'abc123',
        public_hostname: '0.0.0.0'
      }
    }

    post '/api/v1/instances', params: params

    expect(response.body).to eq('asdf')
  end
end
```